# Use of Error typeclass

Tags: haskell, error-handling, typeclass

What is the use of `Error` typeclass:

```
class Error a where
    noMsg :: a
    strMsg :: String -> a
```

There is also another typeclass named `MonadError` which makes sense in monadic computation. But where is `Error` used ? I haven't seen the usage of `noMsg` and `strMsg` yet anywhere.

Comment: Hint: `throwError :: (Monad m, Error e) => e -> ErrorT e m a`

Comment: @CatPlusPlus It's type is like this: `throwError :: MonadError e m => e -> m a`

Comment: There is an instance `(Monad m, Error e) => MonadError e (ErrorT e m)`. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.2/docs/Control-Monad-Error-Class.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For historical reasons, the `Monad m` typeclass includes `fail :: String -> m a`. For `Either e` to implement such a method, we must have a way to turn a `String` into an `e`; the `Error` typeclass was invented to allow this via `strMsg`. The addition of `noMsg` is an additional convenience.